# Azure VM subdomain

Tags: azure, dns, subdomain, virtual-machine

I have an Azure VM and I've pointed it with my domain. 
I wish to know if it is possible to create a subdomain that points to a new site on the same VM

PS - It is a Windows server 2012 and I use IIS.

Moved to ServerFault

Comment: This is a question for ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure a host header for each site if you will be hosting multiple sites on the same machine. This will allow you to have one IP address for the VM and IIS will redirect to the correct site based on the host header in the request.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(v=ws.10).aspx